# Proof for divisibility on a prime test: $\frac{(p-1)!}{(n!(p-n)!)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

$p$ is a prime only if

$\forall n \in\{ 2, 3, .. ,\lfloor \frac{p}{2}-1\rfloor, \lfloor \frac{p}{2}\rfloor \}$:
$\dfrac{(p-1)!}{n!(p-n)!}\in \mathbb N$

The remainders and $n$'s that don't divide when $p$ is not prime seem to be factors or contain factors.

What is the proof or how does this work?

(This was re-tested and works.)

Comment: What does $int(x)$ denote? The integral? Integer? In that case rounded, ceiling, or floor?

Comment: integer by the floor.

Comment: $P_n, n\geq 2 \implies P_n = 2k-1 \implies$ Pun intended

Comment: The $\frac{p}{2}+1$ is wrong. Take $p = 4$. Then $n = 3$, and $\frac{3!}{3!\cdot 1!} = 1$ is an integer.

Comment: In my book, $4-1 = 3$, so $(p-1)! = 3!$.

Comment: So it only works for n>1 and (p-n)>1

Comment: I just came here to read comments...

Comment: This questions doesn't work, I can't remember the original equation, does someone know what it was?

Comment: I found what I'm trying to give an equation to: http://ptri1.tripod.com/ at Prime Numbers

Comment: I found the equation: p must divide p!/2!(p-2)! and p!/3!(p-3)! which also works for n=floor(p/2) and n=floor(p/2+1)

Comment: @Mark so there are two conditions? The test must holds for both?

Comment: Yes it must hold for both and for all others. I checked more and for pCn, n will not divide p if n is a factor or p. I will update it again.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question, still unanswered here (surprisingly), with a ready answer on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Divisibility_properties).

If $p$ is prime, then $p$ divides $\binom{p}{n}$ for any $0<n<p$ (since $p$ divides the numerator, but not the denominator, of $\binom{p}{n}=\frac{p(p-1)\cdots(p-n+1)}{n!}$). Conversely, if $p$ is composite, and $q$ is a prime divisor of $p$, then $p$ doesn't divide $\binom{p}{q}$. Indeed, otherwise $\frac{(q-1)!}{p}\binom{p}{q}=\frac{(p-1)\cdots(p-q+1)}{q}$ would be an integer (but $q$ can't divide the numerator, since it is prime and doesn't divide $p-k$ for $0<k<q$).